# iOS Xcode email attachment doesn't deliver text "in" correct format

Tags: xcode, email, email-attachments

I have a simple columnar text report that I store in the documents directory i.e

------------ Report by Store ------------

Store: Vegas Outlet     Manager: Joe Smith
   Address 123 Story Lane
   Las Vegas, NV 12345
   Sales 3000.00

Store: New York         Manager: Frank Jones
   Address 321 Broadway
   Mew York, NY 12345
   Sales 5555.00

Store: St Louis Outlet  Manager: Ozzie Davis
   Address 88 Main Street
   St Louis Vegas, MI 12345
   Sales 3333.00

When I attach it to an email programaticaly in Xcode and send it, all spacing and CRs diappear. when I open the email and view the attachment I get:

------------ Report by Store ------------Store: Vegas OutletManager:JoeSmithAdddress 123 Story LaneLas Vegas, NV 12345Sales 3000.00Store: New YorkManager:Frank JonesAddress 321 BroadwayMew York, NY 12345Sales 5555.00Store: St Louis Outlet  Manager: OzzieDavisAddress 88 Main StreetSt Louis Vegas, MI 12345Sales 3333.00

When I attach the exact same file to an email using gmail yahoo ...

the format is correct

I've tried mimeType:@"text/plain", mimeType:@"text/csv", mimeType:@"html"

anybody else run into this?

Here's the code

```
NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"ReportSomething.txt";
NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];

NSString *textFromFile = @"";

textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *emailTitle = @"Report from home Office";
NSString *messageBody = @"See Attached Report";

// To address
// NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"whoEver@gmail.com"];

[self getDefaultEmail];

//   NSArray *toRecipents = defEmail;
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defEmail];



MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// here's where the problem is 
[mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:fileName];
 //   [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/x-pdf" fileName:fileName];


// Present mail view controller on screen

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

again I attach the file using safari browser / gmail and receive in the correct format

attach it / mail it - using iOS NO format

Comment: Does it have Windows, Unix, or Mac line breaks?

Comment: Actually look at the text as `NSData`. Personally I would just fire-up Charles Proxy and look at what was being sent. It may not be popular these days but to be a competent programmer one needs to be able to read hex and recognize at least a few rings such as LF, CR.

Comment: I end each line of the text file with with "\r"  tried "\r\n" no difference.  Bring it up in textWrangler - looks fine